# How much cost would artificial pollination add to common products (fruits etc.)?

Tags: botany, ecology, environment, ecosystem, pollination

I've read about ecosystem services and their possible valuation - statements like "honeybee pollination service in the US is worth 1.6 billion dollars".

Is data available on how this would affect the cost a consumer pays for a given product? For example if the humans must do all pollination of fruits themselves, how would that affect the retail cost of these fruit?

Comment: I've made some pretty big edits because I think I understood what you're getting at. However, if I've changed your meaning, let me know and I'll revert back to the original!

Answer (score 5):

The cost would increase; either because pollination services are not provided and the supply is decreased; or because the cost to producers goes up as they must pay for artificial pollination. See the extremely detailed analysis in [Winfree et al](http://nature.berkeley.edu/kremenlab/Articles/Valuing%20Pollination%20Services%20to%20Agriculture.pdf).

*edit*

I imagine what you're actually asking for is a $ figure "per apple". This depends on the location, crop, market, etc., but just for a ballpark, if I'm reading the supplementary tables in [Allsop et al](http://www.plosone.org/article/info%3adoi/10.1371/journal.pone.0003128) correctly, the replacement value of insect pollination to apples in the Western Cape of South Africa would represent a **6%-25% increase in production cost** (and, if the producers pass that along to the consumers, an equal increase in the cost to consumer).

- [**Allsopp MH, de Lange WJ, Veldtman R**. 2008. Valuing insect pollination services with cost of replacement. PLoS ONE 3: e3128–e3128.](http://dx.doi.org/10.1371/journal.pone.0003128)
- [**Winfree, Gross, Kremen**. 2011. Valuing pollination services to agriculture. Ecol Econ 71: 9–9.](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/j.ecolecon.2011.08.001) [behind paywall, but [posted free here](http://nature.berkeley.edu/kremenlab/Articles/Valuing%20Pollination%20Services%20to%20Agriculture.pdf)]

Comment: I'm unsure about the 6%-25% figure; and would love to see other answers.

Comment: Does "replacement value" mean pollination by hand (= no pollination by nature - animals/insects or weather/wing)?

Comment: Yes; Allsop et al value several different methods (hence the range 6-25) of human-assisted pollination, considering their costs, the resulting yield, etc.